# How to correctly deserialize a message with variable length array?

Tags: ros-melodic, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm receiving some data from serial port and want to deserialize the byte stream I received to a ROS message.

The serial port data contains **variable** number of elements (elements with same type). So I use variable length array in my ROS message.

For example I have received these bytes in memory:

```
uint8_t buffer[] = { 0x02, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x12, 0x12, 0x12, 0x12, 0x13, 0x13, 0x13, 0x13 };
```

Here,

- `0x02` means 2 elements in the variable length array,
- `(0x01010101, 0x02020202, 0x03030303)` is the first element, this is actually a 3-dimensional point with float type,
- `(0x11111111, 0x12121212, 0x13131313)` is the second element.

And I'm going to use this message:

```
uint8 array_size    # will be 0x02
geometry_msgs/Point32[] points    # will be a array with length 2, the first Point32 is (0x01010101, 0x02020202, 0x03030303), and the second one is (0x11111111, 0x12121212, 0x13131313)
```

---

It seems the [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/MessagesSerializationAndAdaptingTypes) does not work with variable length array. I checked the [code](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/roscpp_serialization/html/structros_1_1serialization_1_1VectorSerializer_3_01T_00_01ContainerAllocator_00_01typename_01boo43b04a606361a9f4d3d545d46d9ec341.html), and there is a serializer for `std::vector`.

But the deserialization process goes wrong in this function:

```
// (line 348 of serialization.h)
template<typename Stream>
inline static void read(Stream& stream, VecType& v)
{
    uint32_t len;
    stream.next(len);
    v.resize(len);    // <----
    IteratorType it = v.begin();
    IteratorType end = v.end();
    for (; it != end; ++it)
    {
        stream.next(*it);
    }   
}
```

It seems the deserializer will change the length of the vector first. But the value of variable `len` gets very huge and `v.resize(len)` fails.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/354831/how-to-correctly-deserialize-a-message-with-variable-length-array?/) by [Ekaradon](https://answers.ros.org/users/22251/ekaradon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-06-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dragonslayer](https://answers.ros.org/users/38812/dragonslayer/) on 2020-06-13**:
You could try union. Why not use a vector instead of the dynamic array?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-06-14**:
Note: the link (ie: "the code") points to the DiamondBack version of this. As this is really low-level functionality, it most likely hasn't changed in the important parts, but I would recommend you use either the repository that hosts the code, or at least use a more up-to-date set of documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This could be an [xy-problem](http://xyproblem.info), but ignoring that for now:

> It seems the tutorial does not work with variable length array.

the code shown in the tutorial is most likely fine, the problem is likely in the buffer you present to `deserialize(..)`:

- `len` is of type `uint32_t`
- `buffer` is an array of `uint8_t`

this will most likely lead `stream.next(len)` to read 4 bytes from `buffer` and consider them all part of `len`.

This makes `len` equal to `0x01010102` (little endian), which is `16843010` decimal.

The correct byte sequence for `2` would be `0x02 0x00 0x00 0x00`.

Finally: please describe what you are attempting to do, as unless you're implementing your own client library (and implement TCPROS from scratch) it seems unlikely that normal use of ROS would require you to deal with any of this.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ekaradon](https://answers.ros.org/users/22251/ekaradon/) on 2020-06-15**:
The correct byte sequence for 2 would be 0x02 0x00 0x00 0x00 at the first 4 bytes of `buffer`, and `uint8 array_size` should be deleted from msg file.